# C# - Get bytes from file at known offset

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

As a wee fore-note, this is me first proper C# program, and me experience with programming is mostly with making Pascal scripts for TES5Edit. Made two actual programs in Lazarus but, err, they're pretty terrible.

Uploaded me current code 'ere: http://www.mediafire.com/download/fadr8bc8d6fv7cf/WindowsFormsApplication1.7z

Anyhow! What I'm currently trying to do, is get the byte values at two specific offsets in a .dds file. The x resolution is kept @ offset +0c, and consists of two bytes (so +0c and +0d). Same gig for the y resolution; @ offset +10 & +11. I uploaded me findings here: http://pastebin.com/isBKwaas

I've no clue how to do this, however. The most I've been able to decipher from various google results, has resulted with this:

```
        public void GetDDSDimensions(string strDDSFilename, out int iSourceDDSx, out int iSourceDDSy)
    {
        FileStream fsSourceDDS = new FileStream(strDDSFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        int iWidthOffset = 12; // 0c in hex, if byte is 00, then size is => 256, so get +0d as well
        int iHeightOffset = 16; // 10 in hex, same gig as above. Get byte @ +11 if +10 is 00.
        byte[] bufferDDSBytes = new byte[24]; // @ Offset +24 , byte is always 01. Use as a wee, err, "landmark".

    }
```

No clue how to move on from there. I need to somehow set bufferDDSBytes to nab the first 24 bytes in fsSourceDDS, then compare the hex values @ +0c and +10, in order to get the resolution of the .dds file.

Comparing should be easy; C# should have a hex equivalent to Pascal's StrToInt() function, no?

Comment: So basically you are asking how to read Little-endian encoded `ushort` from a specific file offset.

Comment: Right, uh, LE and BE is to do with the order of the bytes; so in LE, the hex value 4000 is written as '00 40', but in BE, it's written as '40 00', aye? And ushort just seems to be a small integer variable.

Comment: Correct. Actually looking at the data, most likely they are LE `int` s (4 bytes) at offset 0xc, 0xc+4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, use `using` :-)

```
using (FileStream fsSourceDDS = new FileStream(strDDSFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
     // do something with the FileStream
} // Ensures that it is properly closed/disposed
```

To go to a specific offset in the stream, use the `Seek` method:

```
fsSourceDDS.Seek(someOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

and call `ReadByte` or `Read` method on it to get as many bytes as you want. After reading bytes, the position in the stream is advanced by the number of bytes read. You can get the current position in the stream with the `Position` property. To read little-endian values directly from the stream, you can use the `BinaryReader` class.

To combine all of the above:

```
using (FileStream fsSourceDDS = new FileStream(strDDSFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fsSourceDDS))
{
    fsSourceDDS.Seek(0x0c, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ushort with = binaryReader.ReadUInt16();
    fsSourceDDS.Seek(0x10, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ushort height = binaryReader.ReadUInt16();
}
```

Comment: `BitConverter` is not guaranteed to use little endian. The correct class to be used is `BinaryReader`.

Comment: Slowly working through the documentation. Forgive me fer not posting promptly, I code at a snail's pace. When you use the 'Seek()' function, I take it that it passes the returned value to the next function? Seems similar to Assembly's 'cmp' and 'je' functions; when the former is called, the result is chucked to the next line of code, which is usally je (or some derivative), that is (not) passed depending on if the cmp returned true or false.

Comment: The whole thing can be shortened to `using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(strDDSFilename))) { reader.BaseStream.Position = 0xc; int width = reader.ReadInt32(); int height = reader.ReadInt32(); }` +1 anyway.

Comment: @MajinCry: (Un)fortunately, I don't know Assembler, so Im not sure I understand your question correctly. Are you familiar with OO (object oriented programming) and the concept of classes? If not, you should read into it. `Seek` (as many instance methods) modifies the state of the `FileStream` instance (here fsSourceDDS), you can ignore the returned value in this case, it "knows" the current position. But explaining this is going to be too long for a comment..